# CodeIgniter's form_hidden

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I achieve this:

```
//view.php
<input type="hidden" name="Name" value="<?php echo $variable->id; ?>"
```

using CodeIgniter’s form_hidden helper:

```
//view.php
<?php echo form_hidden('Name','<?php echo $variable->id; ?>') ?>
```

The first one works fine when I display $variable->id but CI's form_hidden doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The form helpers are evaluated when the script is run, just like any other script, so you do this:

`<?php echo form_hidden('Name', $variable->id); ?>`

If you have shorttags enabled, you could do:
`<?=form_hidden('Name', $variable->id);?>`

Answer (score 2):

Here are the complete details for the form helper class of CodeIgniter:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html